# What are the elements of dihedral group $\mathbb{D_6}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, dihedral-groups

I'm not really all that good with dihedral groups and can't find anything online that explicitly shows the elements of $\mathbb{D_6}$

Comment: What do you mean by your question? The elements are just any six symbols and you get an operation given by the group table. I don't quite understand what you could be asking.

Comment: Do you know about **group's presentation**?

Comment: Some authors write $D_3$ for the dihedral group with $6$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

$D_6\cong S_3$ and is the set of symmetries of an equilateral triangle.  Three rotations and three reflections.

Equivalently, it's the set of permutations (bijections) of a three element set, say $\{1,2,3\}$.

Btw, it has the distinction of being the smallest non-abelian group.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris is probably right. There is more about this group [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6):

If you are not sure look also to cycle graphs of [dihedral groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group). See there is $D_3$ (which could have name $D_6$) is isomorphic to $S_3$. And there is $D_6$ group symmetry of David star, which is $D_3 \times Z_2 $ which has 12 elements.